# Strange missing space on SATA RAID 1 disc in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata, raid-1

A have windows 10 pro installation(clean install) that was created around 10 month ago(mb ASUS Z87-DELUXE).

I didnt notice it in the beginning but the space of one of disc started to disapperaring. My first guess was that one of SATA RAID 1 discs was getting corrupted.
But according to *Intel Rapid* program the discs are healty.
If i run *windirstat* i says that 49,5Gb of the disc is used.
If i look on *My Computer* the entire disc is full. If I select all folders(hidden also) in explorer and select properties it says the the entire disc uses 53,5Gb.

If use Storage sense in windows settings is said that 736Gb i used for apps(!?)(the disc is 781Gb large)
If I click the app it only shows a program installation that uses 136Mb.
I also have en development installation of MS SQL but the entire folders is only 8Gb.

So my guess is that its Windows thats using the space, but for what? Any suggestions would be appricated. Sure I can always copy the entire content to another disc and then format the disc and move it back and remount the database in SQL. But not knowing is very annoying...

(yes I have a full antivirus installation, ESET Internet security)

(System restore is turned of for this disc.. and for c drive its just 10Gb)

[Result from storage sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPe1A.png)

```
*L:\>chkdsk  
The type of the file system is NTFS.  
Volume label is Liten lagring.  
WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.  
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.  

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...  
  395264 file records processed.  
File verification completed.  
 Phase duration (File record verification): 4.51 seconds.
  1054 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.  
  0 bad file records processed.  
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.54 milliseconds.  

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...  
  67141 reparse records processed.  
  452478 index entries processed.  
Index verification completed.  
 Phase duration (Index verification): 25.67 seconds.  
  0 unindexed files scanned.  
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 203.33 milliseconds.  
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.  
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.60 milliseconds.  
  67141 reparse records processed.  
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 152.03 milliseconds.  

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...  
Security descriptor verification completed.  
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 21.87 milliseconds.  
  28608 data files processed.  
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.42 milliseconds.  
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...  
  39364112 USN bytes processed.  
Usn Journal verification completed.  
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 1.13 seconds.  
The Volume Bitmap is incorrect.  
Windows has checked the file system and found problems.  
Please run chkdsk /scan to find the problems and queue them for repair.  
 819199999 KB total disk space.  
 818417336 KB in 266141 files.  
     93696 KB in 28609 indexes.  
         0 KB in bad sectors.  
    524975 KB in use by the system.  
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.  
    163992 KB available on disk.  
      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.  
 204799999 total allocation units on disk.  
     40998 allocation units available on disk.  
Total duration: 31.70 seconds (31704 ms).

L:\>chkdsk /scan  
The type of the file system is NTFS.  
Volume label is Liten lagring.  
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...  
  395264 file records processed.  
File verification completed.  
 Phase duration (File record verification): 4.49 seconds.  
  1054 large file records processed.  
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.  
  0 bad file records processed.  
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.60 milliseconds.
  
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...  
  67141 reparse records processed.  
  452478 index entries processed.  
Index verification completed.  
 Phase duration (Index verification): 25.77 seconds.  
  0 unindexed files scanned.  
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 179.18 milliseconds.  
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.  
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 3.11 milliseconds.  
  67141 reparse records processed.  
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 163.17 milliseconds.  

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...  
Security descriptor verification completed.  
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 12.04 milliseconds.  
  28608 data files processed.  
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.57 milliseconds.  
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...  
  39365376 USN bytes processed.  
Usn Journal verification completed.  
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 1.05 seconds.  

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.  
No further action is required.  
 819199999 KB total disk space.  
 818417336 KB in 266141 files.  
     93696 KB in 28609 indexes.  
         0 KB in bad sectors.  
    524975 KB in use by the system.  
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.  
    163992 KB available on disk.  
      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.  
 204799999 total allocation units on disk.  
     40998 allocation units available on disk.  
Total duration: 31.69 seconds (31691 ms).  
L:\>*
```

Comment: Have you tried running `chkdsk`?

Comment: Added chkdsk result to mainpost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was SQL Server -> log -> Polybase -> dump
Didn't even know it was installed.
Installed Treesize and there it shows up.
Now I need to figure how to empty that, automatically or remove it entirely